# Opera ignoring float:left;

Tags: css, css-float, opera

I'm having the problem with: `<div class='navbar_item navbar_item_active font_colaboratelight' id='nav_".$navbarlink_id."_active' style='float:left;color:#ffffff;'>`

The elements inside float just fine... I've been trying everything, but the only way I'm fixing this is to set a width on the floated elements, which is very unpractical, because I don't know their contents...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
echo "<div style='width:960px;height:37px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'>
    <div style='height:37px;background:url(/system/images/navbar/background/1.png);position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;z-index:-1;'></div>
        <div id='navbar_content' style='line-height:0px;width:960px;'>";


            // get navbar shortcuts
            $links = frontend_getnavbarlinks("sid_".$shop_id,$lang);

            foreach($links as &$link){

                $navbarlink_id = $link['id'];

                $link_section_arr = explode(':',$link['section']);
                $sectionlink_type = $link_section_arr[0];
                $sectionlink_id = $link_section_arr[1];

                if($link_section_arr[0] == 'c'){
                    $href = "/catalog/".$sectionlink_id."/";
                }

                echo "
                <a href='".$href."' class='toggle_reconstruct'>

                <div class='navbar_item navbar_item_active font_colaboratelight' id='nav_".$navbarlink_id."_active' style='float:left;color:#ffffff;'>
                    <div style='float:left;'><img src='/system/images/navbar/background_active/1_left.png'></div>
                    <div style='float:left;background:url(/system/images/navbar/background_active/1_middle.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;height:37px;'>
                        <div style='float:left;color:#E46F7B;font-size:15px;margin-right:6px;margin-left:6px;margin-top:12px;'>".$link['info']['label']."</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style='float:left;'><img src='/system/images/navbar/background_active/1_right.png'></div>
                    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
                </div>

                <div class='navbar_item navbar_item_inactive font_colaboratelight nav_btn_".$sectionlink_type.$sectionlink_id."' id='nav_".$navbarlink_id."_inactive' style='float:left;color:#ffffff;'>
                    <input type='text' value='".$link['does_expand']."' class='nav_expand_indicator' style='display:none;'>
                    <input type='text' value='".$navbarlink_id."' class='nav_section_id' style='display:none;'>
                    <input type='text' value='".$sectionlink_id."' class='nav_sectionlink_id' style='display:none;'>

                    <div style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;height:37px;'>
                        <div style='float:left;color:#ffffff;font-size:15px;margin-right:6px;margin-left:6px;margin-top:12px;'>".$link['info']['label']."</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </a>
                ";

            }



                echo "
                <div style='clear:both;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>



    <div id='navbar_expand1'></div>";
```

Comment: Does Opera treat it like `float:none`? Can you share a link or make screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

try it by giving float : left to the div navbar_content

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

It might be helpful to you..

'display: inline-block'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for some reason opera keeps setting my font-size to 0px, when not declared otherwise, so I had to set font-size:1px; where there was no font-size needed or set explicitly...